# Scala file symbols in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, following file symbols(image also shows partial file name) are displayed:

[image]

I can understand first three symbols. What does last one stand for?

Comment: In my installation of IntelliJ Idea 2017.3 a _Scala Worksheet_ has such icon (you can see it in "New -> ..." context menu entry in the project files tree). I'm not sure, though, nothing else has the same icon and that everything is likewise in Idea 2018.1. I'm not very familiar with Scala Worksheets, AFAIK it is kind of REPL, but documentation probably knows more :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

1. File MyClass.scala with class MyClass
2. File MyClass1.scala with object MyClass1
3. File MyClass2.scala with trait MyClass2
4. File MyClass4.scala with class MyClass4 and companion object MyClass4
5. File MyClass5.scala with trait MyClass5 and companion object MyClass5
6. File MyClass6.scala that contains not only (or different from) object, trait or class MyClass6 (and possibly its companion object). For example here file MyClass6.scala contains class MyClass6 and class MyClass7.

And yes, Scala worksheet has the same icon as 6.

Comment: additionally, it's a prerequisite that the __filename__ itself is identical to the e.g. Scala object name, otherwise the grey "fallback" Icon of `MyClass6` is issued.

Comment: @HartmutPfarr That's what I meant by "or different from".

Answer (score 1):

The last one icon is the symbol for **scala worksheet**. which has the extension of `.sc`.

You can create as `File -> New -> Scala Worksheet`

> A worksheet is a Scala file that is evaluated on save, and the result
> of each expression is shown in a column to the right of your program.
> Worksheets are like a REPL session on steroids, and enjoy 1st class
> editor support: completion, hyperlinking, interactive
> errors-as-you-type, auto-format, etc.

More details on [Scala Worksheet in Intellij is here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2012/12/04/scala-worksheet/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The last one stands for a .sc file that contains Scala worksheet (File > New > Scala Worksheet)